# True Fixed Width Fonts in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to parse Lab Data from an Microsoft Access Database I've already formatted all the data but text tables (Tables created with ASCII Chars) do not display correctly. I'm using a fixed pitch font (Couier New) but the pitch seems to not be fixed when printing Underscores in markup eveything looks fine but when printing the underscored lines come up short.

Comment: If you are displaying your text in a LABEL, then the underscores are being eaten as flags for hot-keys.  Be sure you are using a `TextBlock` as James Kovacs suggests, or a `TextBox`.  You can set them `IsReadonly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"` to simulate a Label that doesn't do hot-keys.

Answer (score 31):

The following XAML aligns correctly both on screen (in XamlPad) and on printer (HP CP2025):

```
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="30">ABCDEFGHI</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="30">A_C_E_G_I</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
```

I would check your font substitution settings on your printer.

Comment: Can you give us some XAML that fails to display properly? Are you sure there isn't some style or code that is changing the font?